# irreducibility in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've read somewhere that $q\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[X]$ is irreducible iff $\forall a\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z:q (a)\neq0$. Now for degree one polynomials its not true. For higher degree it is true that if $q(a)=0$ for some $a$ then $q$ is reducible. But I couldn't verify the stronger statement. ($p$ a prime)

Comment: if $p(a)=0$ then $x-a$ divides $p(x)$

Comment: The statement $q(x) \in \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is irreducible $\iff$ $q(a)\neq0,\forall a \in \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is true only if the degree of $q$ is $2$ or $3$. Otherwise not. Consider $x^4 + x^2+1$ over $\Bbb{F}_2[X]$. While if $q(a)=0$ for some $a\in \Bbb{F}_p$ then look at the comment of janmarqz.

Comment: Ok, but the case 2 and 3 is true in any field, so nothing special in these?

Comment: @Ale $ $ **Counterexample** $\ (2x\!-\!1)^2 $ over $\,\Bbb Z/4$ has no roots but is reducible.

Comment: I think you need to have $p$ a prime number, otherwise you are right @Billdubuque.

Answer (score 1):

Over *any* field, the product of two irreducible polynomials of degree $>1$ is a reducible polynomial with no roots in that field.